# SQL Server - copy data from staging table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using staging tables to perform validation and insert into live.

Suppose I have a table **PERSONS**

```
TABLE Persons
(
Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
HouseNumber int,
)
```

and a **STAGING TABLE** as follows

```
TABLE Persons_Staging
(
Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
HouseNumber varchar(255),
)
```

I need to write a procedure to transfer data from the **staging table** to the **live table** while ensuring no duplicates are inserted. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't done something like this manually for years, and have come to see this sort of task as entirely non-productive. This may not be an option for right now, but long term, consider getting a database comparison tool. These are designed to do all the heavy lifting, leaving you free to focus on development work. I use Redgate's tools. They have a free trial. http://www.red-gate.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command.

Something like this:

```
MERGE 
    INTO Persons AS TARGET
    USING Persons_Staging AS SOURCE
    ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
    --WHEN MATCHED
    --    THEN UPDATE???
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT (Id , LastName , FirstName, HouseNumber)
    VALUES (SOURCE.Id , SOURCE.LastName , SOURCE.FirstName, SOURCE.HouseNumber)
    -- WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    --    THEN DELETE???
;
```

If you want to update existing records you uncomment the `UPDATE` part and add a suitable update clause. The same with the delete part.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get this to work using the MERGE command!

Answer (score 0):

you could use this with a left outer join on both tables to get all the data that isn't the same. That data you then can insert into your column

```
INSERT INTO Tab1(front,end,number)
SELECT first,last,nr from tab2 LEFT OUTER JOIN tab1 ON front = first AND last = end AND convert(int,number) = CONVERT(int,nr)
WHERE tab1.ID is null
```

this could work, on the other hand there are tools made for this kind of stuff